# Transfer email accounts to another domain

Tags: email, plesk

i want to transfer the **domain.org** emails accounts to **domain.tn** to make the domain **domain.org** an alias domain for the domain **domain.tn**.

So is this poosible ?

Comment: There is no such functional in Plesk.

Comment: is there a solution for doing that manually ?

Comment: In plesk, create new mail accounts on domain.tn with same names as on domain.org. On server, copy content from /var/qmail/mailnames/domain.org/somemail/ to /var/qmail/mailnames/domain.tn/somemail/. Fix permissions to popuser:popuser.

Comment: Thank you but can this be automatically done through the **database** ? because i have too many accounts and i don't want to change their passwords.

Comment: It's dangerous to trying does it just via database. And it's not so difficult to automate it via shell. The main reason of creating same emails to domain.tn it's for sure that all necessary file structures will be done properly. I'll show you how to change passwords of new accounts to old passwords.

Answer (score 4):

As I already said, the easiest way to transfer mail accounts between subscriptions it is
create new mail accounts on target domain with same names as on source domain. 
It's can be automated with shell script and PLesk CLI utility /usr/local/psa/bin/mail - just get list of folder in /var/qmail/mailnames/domain.org/ and in loop call:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/mail -c <mail>@domain.tn -passwd <somerandompass>
```

The issues here is that you will miss account aliases.

The next step it's a coping of content from /var/qmail/mailnames/domain.org/somemail/ to /var/qmail/mailnames/domain.tn/somemail/. Fix permissions to popuser:popuser if needed.

So now you have mail accounts on domain.tn with same names as on domain.org.
The problem is here that you have created this accounts with some temporary passwords and you need to change it as on domain.org.

So, following query shows current and old passwords of account with **same** name on this domains:

```
SELECT
    domains.name, mail.mail_name, account_id, dom_id, password, passfrom 
FROM accounts
    INNER JOIN mail ON accounts.id = mail.account_id 
    INNER JOIN domains ON domains.id = mail.dom_id 
    INNER JOIN (select mail_name, password passfrom from mail, domains, accounts where domains.name = 'domain.org' and domains.id = dom_id and accounts.id = account_id) tfrom ON mail.mail_name = tfrom.mail_name  
WHERE 
    domains.name = 'domain.tn';
```

And following query makes it equivalent:

```
UPDATE accounts 
    INNER JOIN mail ON accounts.id = mail.account_id 
    INNER JOIN domains on domains.id = mail.dom_id
    INNER JOIN (select mail_name, password passfrom from mail, domains, accounts where domains.name = 'domain.org' and domains.id = dom_id and accounts.id = account_id) tfrom ON mail.mail_name = tfrom.mail_name 
SET
    password = passfrom
WHERE
    domains.name = 'domain.to';
```

Comment: Thank you.

Account created with this command line are not accessible.

I have tried this command :

`/usr/local/psa/bin/mail -c test@domain.tn -passwd 000000`

But i can't have access to it.

Comment: tail -f /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog and try to login to account, what happens in log?